# Find the number of functions

Tags: combinatorics

How many functions $f : \{0,1\}^n \mapsto \{0,1\}$ have the equal number of function values $0$ and $1$? I have the answer to the question: $ \sum_{k=0}^{2^{n-1}} 2^{n-1}\binom{2n}{2k}\binom{2k}{k}$, where $k$ is the number of function value $1$ or function value $0$.
Could please someone explain me how to solve this kind of exercises?

Comment: The functions $f : X → \{0, 1\}$ are in 1 to 1 correspondence with subsets of $X$. This question is really about choosing subsets, which is why $n \choose k$ turns up. Unfortunately I don't really understand your question. Is is about functions which have $2^{n-1}$ zeroes? Is is about the set of function with $m$ zeroes, for a fixed $m$? Is it something else? Pleas clarify your question.

Comment: @RolfSievers no, it's not about functions which have $2^{n-1}$ zeroes. This is about functions that have equal number of zeroes and ones in function values. For example, for $n=2$ we have $4$ arguments: $0, 1, 0, 1$ and $2$ possible function values: $0$ and $1$. We're interested in functions, which have 0 zeroes and 0 ones, 1 zero and 1 one or two zeroes and two ones in their function values.

Comment: We sum up from $k=0$ to $2^{n-1}$ because $2^{n-1}$ is the maximum number of zeroes or ones. I mean, we can have at most $2^{n-1}$ zeroes and $2^{n-1}$ ones as function values.

Comment: But if $k$ is the number of zeros and also the number of ones then $k+k=2^n$ right? It must equal the total number of values, since the function cannot take other values.

Comment: The $f$ in your question cannot take values $\notin\{0,1\}$. Are you sure of that? If it *can* take other values then the expression $\sum_{k=0}^{2^{n-1}}\binom{2n}{2k}\binom{2k}{k}$ comes in sight.

Answer (score 2):

These functions have a domain that has $2^n$ elements.

Moreover they correspond one to one with subsets of the domain having $2^{n-1}$ elements (the sets $\{x\in\{0,1\}^n\mid f(x)=1\}$).

There are: $$\binom{2^n}{2^{n-1}}$$ subsets of $\{0,1\}^n$ that have $2^{n-1}$ elements.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I was not asking for another solution, I'm trying to understand the solution I've already got.

Comment: Did you find that solution yourself? In e.g. special case $n=1$ it gives $\binom20\binom00+\binom22\binom21=1.1+1.2=3$ as outcome. Can that be correct? Quote: "We're interested in functions wich have $0$ zeroes an $0$ ones,...in their function value". They simply do not exist in this context.

Comment: The solution was given by the prof.

Comment: If no mistakes were made then there must be some misunderstanding then between you and the prof or you and me. Again: can $f$ only take the values $0$ and $1$? If so then my solution is okay and yours is not.